# next dev doesn't keep running, stops automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, yarnpkg

Im trying to run a Next v13.1.6 project, i just created it using yarn create next-app but
for some reason, when i run yarn dev, it just stops automatically like if its a build

Here you can see it:

[image]

My package.json looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "nft-generator",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "13.1.6",
    "@types/node": "18.11.18",
    "@types/react": "18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.10",
    "eslint": "8.33.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.6",
    "next": "13.1.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `next dev` to keep it auto restarting on changes. Change `"dev":"next"` to `"dev":"next dev"`